# Grad-CAM, how to fix Attribute Error: 'KerasTensor' object has no attribute '_id'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, image-classification

I've been building an image classification by CNN before, but this is my first-time creating Grad-CAM. I'm just a student who have not much experience in coding so, I have no idea what's going on.
(This task is binary classification)

## **Model**

```
MobileNetV3Large = MobileNetV3Large(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
#Freezing layers
set_trainable = False
for layer in MobileNetV3Large.layers:
  if layer.name == 'expanded_conv_11/expand':
    set_trainable = True
  if set_trainable:
    layer.trainable = True
  else:
    layer.trainable = False
  print("layer name",layer.name, layer.trainable)

def build_model():
  input = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))
  x = preprocess_input(input)
  x = MobileNetV3Large(x)
  x = Flatten()(x)
  x = BatchNormalization()(x)
  x = Dense(256, activation = 'relu')(x)
  x = Dropout(0.3)(x)
  x = BatchNormalization()(x)
  output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
  model = Model(input, output)
  return model

model = build_model()

model.load_weights(weight_dir)
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999),
                loss='binary_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy'])
```

[my model summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsdU0.png)

## **Preprocess image**

```
def preprocess_image(image_path):
  img = load_img(image_path, target_size=(224, 224))
  img_array = img_to_array(img)

  return img_array.reshape((1, 224, 224, 3))
```

## **Grad CAM**

```
def gradcam(model, image_path, class_index):
  processed_image = preprocess_image(image_path)

  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    pred = model(processed_image)
    pred = pred[:, class_index]

  gradients = tape.gradient(pred, model.layers[1].output)

  channel_axis = -1 if len(gradients.shape) == 4 else 1
  pooled_gradients = tf.reduce_mean(gradients, axis=channel_axis)

  upscaled_gradients = tf.image.resize(pooled_gradients, size=(224, 224))

  heatmap = tf.reduce_sum(upscaled_gradients * processed_image, axis=-1)
  heatmap = tf.maximum(heatmap, 0) / tf.math.reduce_max(heatmap)

  return heatmap
```

```
image_path = "/content/gradcam_dataset/image_1.jpg"
class_index = 0

heatmap = gradcam(model, image_path, class_index)
```

### **The error message**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-a9da84400fc7> in <cell line: 4>()
      2 class_index = 0
      3 
----> 4 heatmap = gradcam(model, image_path, class_index)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/imperative_grad.py in imperative_grad(tape, target, sources, output_gradients, sources_raw, unconnected_gradients)
     65         "Unknown value for unconnected_gradients: %r" % unconnected_gradients)
     66 
---> 67   return pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_TapeGradient(
     68       tape._tape,  # pylint: disable=protected-access
     69       target,

AttributeError: 'KerasTensor' object has no attribute '_id'
```

I have spent many hours trying to do and fix it, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you have to build the model that gives multi output, one is the logit and another one is the target feature maps.

Comment: Look [here](https://keras.io/examples/vision/grad_cam/) for a basic example if TF/Keras. Especially at the `make_gradcam_heatmap(...)` function, and how it creates the model. Innat is right, you have to create a model that has both the prediction and the output of the conv layer you want to look at.

Comment: I just fixed it. Thanks very much to both of you. I greatly appreciate that.